# NodeJS Confirm Facebook Credentials

Tags: facebook, node.js, validation, authorization, oauth-2.0

In this scenario I have an app in which:

1. The user is to log in using Facebook Single Sign On (SSO) on a mobile device (iOS in this case).
2. The returned Facebook credentials are then sent to a NodeJS server (using the same Facebook App Key) and need to be validated as truly being that users Facebook credentials before they are associated to a program based account.

The Problem:

Given access to everything returned by Facebook as the result of authentication, how can this data be used to confirm that authorization with Facebook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=TOKENGOESHERE

If a user is returned, and their ID is what the client claims, they are most likely who they say they are.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things you can do:

- Facebook will generally pass you a [signed request](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/signed-request/) which you can check with a basic SHA2 hash. If the hash is correct, you can assume the user was really authenticated using facebook.
- Facebook will generally also pass you a (short lived) [access token](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/access-tokens-and-types/) which you can [exchange for a longer lived access token using the graph api](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/). Upon this exchange completing you are as sure you can be that the user is who he says he is.